# Differences in imported data from one file vs. lots of files

Tags: r

I have built a function which allows me to process .csv files one by one. This involves importing data using the read.csv function, assigning one of the columns a name, and making a series of calculations based on that one column. However, I'm having problems with how to apply this function to a whole folder of files. Once a list of files is generated, do I need to read the data from each file from within my function, or prior to the application of it? This is what I had previously to import the data:

```
AllData <- read.csv("filename.csv", header=TRUE, skip=7)
DataForCalcs <- Data[5]
```

My code resulted in the calculation of a number of variables, which I put into a matrix at the end of the code, and used the apply function to calculate the max of each of those variables.

```
NewVariables <- matrix(c(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3, Variable4, Variable5)
colnames(NewVariables <- c("Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", Variable4", "Variable5")
apply(NewVariables, 2, max, na.rm=TRUE)
```

This worked great, but I then need to write this table to a new .csv file, which contains these results for each of the ~300 files I want to process, preceded by the name of each file. I'm new to this, so I would really appreciate your time helping me out!

Comment: replace `bind(df,u)` with `rbind(df,u)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about reading in all your .csv files in a loop that combines them into one dataframe? I do this all the time like this:

```
df <- c()
for (x in list.files(pattern="*.csv")) {
  u<-read.csv(x, skip=6)
  u$Label = factor(x) #A column that is the filename
  df <- rbind(df,u)
}
```

This of course assumes that every .csv file has an equal number of columns that are named the same thing. But if that assumption is true then you can simply treat the resulting dataframe like one dataframe.

One you have you dataframe entered you can use the Label column as your group by variable. Also you'll need to select only the 5th and 13th variables as well as the label variable. Then if your goal is to take say the max and max values for each .csv file and produce another dataframe of those max values you'd go about it like this.

```
library(dplyr)

df.summary <- df %>%
group_by(Label) %>%
summarise_each(funs(max)) ##Take the max value of each column except Label
```

There are better ways to do this using `gather()` but I don't want to overwhelm you.

Comment: I hadn't considered, but my data is organised in each file with 6 rows of useless data, and the column headings are in the 7th row. What exactly due you mean by the column that id the filename?

Comment: That is easy to deal with. I've made an edit to skip the first 6 rows. And sorry the `$Label` column is just id column consisting of the filename. It can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for that. So what is the result of your code? Will I end up with all of my data arranged into one column? I don't quite understand. If they are all combined, can I still calculate the maximum value for each csv file I imported?

Comment: It depends on how many columns you are starting out with. If you have one column of data in each .csv file then your combined file with have the same. All this code does if read in all the .csv files in a particular directory appending them to the bottom each time.

Comment: Well it's not specifically the max that I'm after, my function will hopefully calculate about 30 vectors' worth of data, and I would like to find the max of each of those vectors. The function is quite big too, so will this method be able to handle it? Each file has about 10 columns of data, but I am only interested in one or two of these to calculate my output.

Comment: We need to align our language. By vectors do you mean a grouping variable? If each .csv file is one vector(or grouping variable) like `Label` and you need the max then the method I described above should be fine. Have you first tried the loop to read your .csv files in?

Comment: I apologise, I'm very new to this. I've been able to import the files individually into the environment, which hasn't been a problem. However, for me to use that data (specifically the 5th column of data for each file), I need my function to identify that column, and name it "Velocity", so that other variables can be calculated from it. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does but what my solution is proposing is the import EVERYTHING into R then apply one function to the whole dataset. So I'll ask again, have you tried to the loop to read your .csv. files in. Not one individual file but ALL of them.

Comment: Yes sorry I have now properly, and using that one data frame (u). I did have a problem with the library(dplyr) bit, what exactly does this do? I assume it groups the variables by the name of each file? I have been able to calculate my variables of interest, and summarise them overall, but could you please show me how to summarise them by filename?

Comment: So the problem I'm facing is that I am trying to group by Label, but that Label is aligned to the raw data, and not aligned to my calculated data. I have a matrix with 30 variables, which I have calculated using two columns in the raw data. How can I firstly line each of these data points up with the Label they were calculated from, and secondly summarise by finding a max of each of these variables for each Label?

Comment: Honestly this is very difficult. Can you post in your question an example of the data you have and the data you want?

Comment: do you have an email address I can contact you on, and I can send you an example file, and what I am trying to do?

Comment: Keep it on SO. Just edit your question to outline EXACTLY what you want to do. Without sounding condescending, part of R is learning how to ask questions.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm now getting an error `Error in summarise_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : argument ".data" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Without seeing your code, this is a little difficult. But that said, have you defined the data argument in summarise?

Comment: I think that I have solved the issue - when importing the data the default data type was as a Factor, so I couldn't summarise these values. By setting the stringsAsFactors to FALSE when importing I seem to have resolved this issue.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. I have a data frame `AllData` which contains the one identifier column `Label` and 35 output columns, which are numbers but include NA values. I simply need to find the maximum of each output column, per Label, and build into a summary matrix (i.e. one row for each Label with 35 max values.

Comment: I've made some changes to the answer. Basically what you need is `summarise_each()`. Can you accept the answer if that works for you?

Comment: sorry, no it didn't work for me. I've changed the question and put my entire code I am using, can you please have a look at it and tell me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: `Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame`